# Laravel Multi-tenancy Best Practices

Tags: laravel, multi-tenant

So we have an Admin Portal web app, a Client Portal web app, and an API app.

Admin Portal is built in Laravel 5.x
Client Portal is built in Laravel 5.y
API is built in Lumen 5.z

Admin Portal:

- Acts like a CMS for our 100 employees to interact with customer data
- This app sits on its own repo “admin_portal”
- This app has its own sub-domain admin.company.com
- Has an `admin` database schema, with `employees` table used for authentication (this table has login email and password of our 100 employees)
- Has pages like reports, tickets etc.

Client Portal:

- Acts like a Customer-facing portal where our 1,000 clients login and
  perform actions like submit information requested and see status of
  their current case
- This app sits on its own repo “client_portal”
- This app has its own sub-domain client.company.com
- Has an `customer` database schema, with `clients` table used for authentication (this table has login email and password of our 1,000
  clients)

API:

- Acts like an API for outsider to interact with our 2 DB schemas
- This app sits on its own repo “api”
- This app has its own sub-domain api.company.com

Pretty much all pages, UIs, features in Admin Portal and Client Portal are different.

However, there are some repeated codes in Admin Portal and Client Portal: models, helper functions (i.e. both apps need to talk to some third-party API or need to generate similar PDFs) etc.

A developer in our team suggested combining Admin Portal, Client Portal, and API into 1 giant multi-tenant Laravel app so we can have less code-base and eaier to maintain.

We’re trying to research:

- Whether we should do this? (in what use-case to implement a multi-tenancy app vs single-tenancy app)
- What are the Pros and Cons (development, deployment, debugging, security, and maintenance)
- Whether it’s doable with Laravel, or what would be the side-effects.

I’d like to have the community to give us your opinions and experiences. A few things to consider though:

- We may want to eventually to lock down Admin Portal to our office IPs only
- API is using OAuth while Admin Portal and Client Portal are not
- We are exploring micro-services like Lambda functions to off load a lot of logic from PHP
- Each app may need a different set of PHP packages/versions (defined in composer.json)
- We are using Bitbucket Pipelines and AWS CodeDeploy, listening on each repo

Highly appreciated and cheers!